# Getting runtime exception while generating build on El-capitan

Tags: ios, build, mono, runtimeexception, osx-elcapitan

I have an mac application by which i am generating ipa and apk builds.This application was running fine without any exceptions when it was on yosemite OS.Now when upgraded to El-Capitan it is giving some unhandled exceptions.I am using xbuild command to generate the build for both android and ios.I am using nstask to execute the commands.Here is the code i am using to generate build.

```
NSTask *task=[[NSTask alloc]init];
task.launchPath=@"/library/Frameworks/Mono.Framework/Commands/xbuild";
task.arguments= @[@"/p:Configuration=AppStore",@"/p:Platform=iPhone",@"/p:BuildIpa=true",@"/target:Build",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/xyz/xyz.sln",NSHomeDirectory() ]];

[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```

Here is the exceptions i am getting

```
Unhandled Exception:
Nested exception detected.
Original Exception: at (wrapper managed-to-native)
object.__icall_wrapper_mono_object_new_fast (intptr) <0x0004f>at Mono.XBuild.CommandLine.MainClass.Main (string[]) <0x00013>

Nested exception:at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.RuntimeType.getFullName (System.RuntimeType,bool,bool) <0x0006b>
at System.RuntimeType.ToString () <0x0002d>
at System.Exception.get_ClassName () <0x0002a>
at System.Exception.ToString () <0x0001f>

[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Nested exception detected.
Original Exception: at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_object_new_fast (intptr) <0x0004f>at Mono.XBuild.CommandLine.MainClass.Main (string[]) <0x00013>

Nested exception:at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.RuntimeType.getFullName (System.RuntimeType,bool,bool) <0x0006b>
at System.RuntimeType.ToString () <0x0002d>
at System.Exception.get_ClassName () <0x0002a>
at System.Exception.ToString () <0x0001f>
```

This is coming only when i upgraded to El-capitan OS.Previously on Yosemite this code was running fine.

I have already disabled the System Integrity Protection but inspite of that the problem is not going.I don't know where this exception is coming from.

Note:When i generate the build through command line tool then it works fine without any exception means exception is coming only when i try to generate the build using code.Thanks